# Is a function from Matlab, compiled as a Python package from Matlab Library Compiler, encrypted?

Tags: matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I made some Matlab scripts for my work and compiled then using Matlab Aplication Compiler (generates .exe) to use in Python scripts using os.system or subprocess.call. But calling these functions are really slow. So i think about using Python package from Matlab Library Compiler with as i saw creates a .ctf file for the functions, but i want to make my code closed for the client and i know that Python is not made for compile or obfuscate code.

My question is if i use this Python Package from Matlab Library Compiler will my code be encrypted for the client?